# Displaying all the values of the repeating id using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I have two columns on the left Column A and Column B COlumn A has the repating ids and columb b has the corresponding values in it. how do i filter the column A VALUES AND show both their corresponding values on right.

Column A Column B 1000 5 1000 ann
2000 chris 2000 56 2001 Beth 3000 Mark 3000 1

output should show: ColumnA, Column B

1000 5, ann 2000 56, beth 3000 Mark, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your exact scenario, but if your A values are in ascending order, you can do this:

First, add the following macro for concatenation:

```
Function ConCat(Delimiter As Variant, ParamArray CellRanges() As Variant) As String
Dim Cell As Range, Area As Variant
If IsMissing(Delimiter) Then Delimiter = ""
For Each Area In CellRanges
    If TypeName(Area) = "Range" Then
        For Each Cell In Area
            If Len(Cell.Value) Then ConCat = ConCat & Delimiter & Cell.Value
        Next
    Else
        ConCat = ConCat & Delimiter & Area
    End If
Next
ConCat = Mid(ConCat, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function
```

Then, put the following formula in your results column:

```
=ConCat(",",INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(D3,$A$1:$A$6,0)&":B"&MATCH(D3,$A$1:$A$6,1)))
```

This basically finds the first and last occurrence of the search value, then concatenates all the values within that range.

Note that this is specifically for date in these cells:

[image: Cell locations]

However, it can be easily modified for wherever your data resides by simply adding the starting data row # (using the ROW() function) to both match results.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this to column C related row and copy for remaining cells.

```
=IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a different output like the attached screenshot on the question.

Answer (score 0):

An example using VBA Autofilter.  Configure the position of Cols A, B, O (output), start and end rows to suit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub xfrMatches()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim colA As Long, colB As Long, strowA, endRowA As Long
Dim colO As Long, stRowO As Long, endRowO As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim crit1 As Variant
Dim tmpStr As String
Dim cl As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

colA = 1
colB = 2
strowA = 2
colO = 7
stRowO = 3

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    With ws
        endRowA = .Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row
        endRowO = .Cells(Rows.Count, colO).End(xlUp).Row
            For c = stRowO To endRowO
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
            crit1 = .Cells(c, colO).Value
                With .Range(.Cells(strowA, colA), .Cells(endRowA, colB))
                    .AutoFilter
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=crit1
                End With
                With .AutoFilter.Range
                    tmpStr = ""
                        For Each cl In .Columns(colB).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            tmpStr = tmpStr & "," & cl.Value
                        Next cl
                    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
                End With
            .Cells(c, colO).Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(tmpStr, 2, Len(tmpStr) - 2)
            Next c
    End With

End Sub
```